# Why does my Selenium command not work?

Tags: jquery, selenium

I'm writing a selenium script that should only start testing after all ajax calls have completed.

Several forums have suggested that I use the following condition (in the waitForCondition command):

```
selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0
```

Unfortunately this keeps throwing an error:

> jQuery is undefined

JQuery is definitely defined on my site. I have also tried substituting the jQuery with $, but get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to do the same in a C# test, instead of the Selenium HTML mode. In a C# test through the RC Server it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to wait for jQuery to have finished loading, try waiting until

```
typeof selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery == 'function'
```

is true, before checking active.

Comment: Nice tip. I don't know if this would have solved the problem or not because I got it working by switching to c# selenium tests (that worked).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active == 0`

The key difference here is the function, you need `getUserWindow()`, not `getCurrentWindow()`

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to make it work within the Selenium IDE.

```
Command: waitForCondition
Taret:   selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active == 0
Value:   30000
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Firefox it could be wrapped in a XPCNativeWrapper. To get around that the "best practice" way to get the window is to called getUserWindow() which handles unwrapping object to become useable.

This is also assuming that jQuery isnt being loaded asynchronously.